# Detect if a tweet is tweeted from a mobile phone

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, twitter, tweepy

I am not sure about how can I tell that a tweet is tweeted from a mobile/smart phone.
I am using Tweepy for the twitter API. Twitter API can only tell us the source/client of a tweet (e.g. Twitter for Android).

That's why the only solution I see, is to compare the name of the client used to tweet to a list of mobile clients. (I should build the list by myself)

The list can be huge, that's why I am searching for another suggestion, hack or magic.
(Alternatively, do you know where can I find a good list of mobile app?)

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you can look at the `source` parameter.

This will give you two interesting things

1. The name of the client.
2. The URL of the client.

I'd suggest a two pronged approach.  Look to see if the name says something like "for Android" or "mobile" - and check whether the URL points to iTunes, play.google, or similar.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twitter_services_and_applications)

> A new app is registered every 1.5 seconds, according to Twitter.

I would suggest looking at the [Top 100 Twitter Applications](http://www.squidoo.com/twitterapps) (or similar) and then build your own list of the most commonly seen apps.